# Prove that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\zeta(n) = \gamma$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers

How do you prove that
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\zeta(n) = \gamma$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Macheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)? This series kind of appeared in one of the questions [I asked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650214/questions-regarding-lnx-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nn-zetan-x); you just need to do some rearranging to get to this series. Here is [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n%3D2%20to%20infinity%20of%20%28-1%29%5E%28n%29%2Fn*zeta%28n%29) calculating the series. I believe I have almost proved it (my calculations below), but I'm unsure at the end. I would also like to see if there is some other way of proving them (I don't think there is, but it would be cool).

**My "proof"** (not sure if it right):

\begin{align} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\zeta(n) & =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^n} \\\\ & = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\frac{1}{k^n}\end{align}

Here I interchange the summations (is it possible to do so?):

\begin{align} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\frac{1}{k^n} & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\frac{1}{k^n} \\\\ & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\frac{1}{k^n}\right)\end{align}

Recall the Taylor series for $\ln(x)$:

$$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}x^n$$

By plugging in $\frac{1}{x}$, changing $x$ to $k$ and multiplying by $-1$ on both sides we get:
$$-\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\frac{1}{k^n}$$

...which is exactly what we need. So plugging the result into the series above we get:

\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\frac{1}{k^n}\right) & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k} - \ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\right) \\\\ & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right) \end{align}

Recall the definition of the Euler-Macheroni constant:
$$\gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty}(H_n - \ln(n))$$

Now clearly the term $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$ is the $H_n$ part of the definition, but here's is where I get a little stuck; how does 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\ln(k)$$

Otherwise I think my proof is quite correct, but can anybody help at the end of it?

Comment: This is a telescopic series. \begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln{\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)}&=\sum_{k=1}^n(\ln{(k+1)}-\ln{(k)})\\&=\ln{(n+1)}\\\end{align}

Comment: @PeterForeman Alright thanks, I didn't realise I could apply it here since I haven't learnt it well enough yet.

Comment: @CasimirRönnlöf You're also fine to interchange the summations, though to be more precise you should separate out the summand when $ k = 1 $ so that you can actually use the Fubini theorem. As it stands, the summand is not $ L^1 $, because the harmonic series over $ n $ for $ k = 1 $ diverges.

Comment: @Starfall Thanks!

Comment: It can be seen as a consequence of this formula : $\ln \Gamma(1 + x) = - \gamma x + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac {( - 1)^{n}}{n}\zeta(n) \, x^{n}$ with $x \to 1$ ; see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h141920p802720).

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh wow, that's cool, since I'm also quite interested in the Gamma function

Comment: Integrate both sides of the  [identity $\displaystyle{\bf\color{black}{6.3.14}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) $\ $over $\displaystyle\left(0,1\right)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't write

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k} - \ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)$$

because both of these two series are divergent. To fix this issue, we use the limit

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k} - \ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\right)  = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{k} - \ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(H_n-\ln(n+1)\right)$$

$$\overset{n+1=m}{=}=\lim_{m\to \infty}\left(H_{m-1}-\ln(m)\right)$$

$$=\lim_{m\to \infty}\left(H_m-\frac1m-\ln(m)\right)$$

$$=\lim_{m\to \infty}\left(H_m-\ln(m)\right)-\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac1m$$

$$=\gamma-0$$